# REGEXP_LIKE AND REGEXP_INSTR which one to use

Tags: regex, oracle

I have the following code which uses `regexp_like()`, but when I write the exp: `^[0-5]\.[\d]+$` to the `regexp_like()`, it doesn't return me the correct result.

Should I use `regexp_instr`?

How do I get to know, which one to use?

Comment: Well, if you don't give us the language you use, what is the input and what you are trying to do, nobody can help you.

Answer (score 2):

They're two different functions with different goals so you should use the one most appropriate to your situation.

- [`REGEXP_LIKE()`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/conditions007.htm#SQLRF00501) returns a Boolean and can only be used in the WHERE clause, it's used when you want to return rows that match a condition.
- [`REGEXP_INSTR()`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions148.htm#SQLRF06300) returns an integer, which indicates the beginning or or end of the matched substring. It does not have to be used in the WHERE clause.

  Essentially, `where regexp_instr(...,...) > 0` is identical to a REGEXP_LIKE but it can be used in a lot more situations.

Please read the linked documentation on both.

As to why your condition doesn't return the correct result it'll be because your regular expression doesn't adequately describe the rows you want returned.

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess here, but I think `regexp_like` is already anchored at the start and end, otherwise `regexp_instr` would be redundant.

Comment: It's not anchored, it's REGEXP_LIKE that's redundant but it's clearer what it's doing.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that your regex engine support the `\d` character class. Try these syntaxes instead *(with regexp_like)*:

```
^[0-5]\.[0-9]+$
```

or

```
^[0-5]\.[[:digit:]]+$
```

Comment: It does support both POSIX and Perl-like syntax, including `\d`.

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle [REGEXP_LIKE](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/conditions007.htm#SQLRF00501) is a [condition](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/conditions.htm#SQLRF005) and [REGEXP_INSTR](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions148.htm#i1239887) is a [function](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions.htm#SQLRF006).

You typically use conditions in the `WHERE` clause and [a few other places](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/conditions001.htm#i1034172). You use functions in *any* expression.

Without more details it's hard to tell which one is more suitable in your case, but ultimately both of them do exactly the same. The representation of result is of course different as per the links above and you have to account for that.

Comment: Although it's described as a condition in the docs it is a function that returns a boolean: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/12698. It just can't be used in an ordinary SQL statement outside the WHERE clause as Oracle does not support the Boolean datatype in SQL.